# Is the any Way to Make a Variable into a file address in C#

Tags: c#

I tried to make a simple app just for giving link to it and it download the direct link through an address and I have to put the name file with format in the directory address so I want something that make it changeable by the user. Any suggestions?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string Link;
        Link = textBox1.Text;

        if (!Directory.Exists(@"C:\Downloaded_Data"))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Downloaded_Data");
        }
        else
        {
        }

        string Dir;
        Dir = @"C:\Downloaded_Data\ + txtName + txtFormat";

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadFile(Link, Dir);

        SoundPlayer Play = new SoundPlayer(@"E:\SteamLibrary\SteamApps\common\GarrysMod\garrysmod\sound\thrusters\jet01.wav");
        Play.Play();
}
```

So I want that `txtName` and `txtFormat` can be changed in the textboxes you know I want them to add to the directory but I don't know how! Maybe becasue I just started :)

Comment: Your question is _extremely_ unclear.  Are you asking how to concatenate strings?

Comment: Or do you want to have [link-like controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188769.aspx) in your app?

Answer (score 0):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.package.aspx There is an API which allows a Stream to be created in such a way that it may have a URI specified which points directly to said stream.

So in short if you have an array or a list and you want to provide a URI to point to the data which can be consumed by a 'Stream' then this class will help.